# SettingsServiceDB "Database is too old and upgrade is required"

Tags: database

I have ran this command after an update
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

all databases are updated except

BdcServiceDatabase, Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended
SettingsServiceDB, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Database, Database is too old and upgrade is required

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: im now runing into the same Problem. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you seek as I'm taking a shot in the dark on this one.  If you are trying to upgrade from SP2010 to SP2013 and you are in need of upgrading system service application databases then view this article.  I've been test upgrading my farm and have upgraded a couple of the service apps and following this article is easy and what got me through it.  Sorry if this isn't your question.

[Upgrade service applications to SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719.aspx)

Comment: No, I don't upgraded from 2010 to 2013, I have installed the March 2013 update. I think that the problem was present before the update, too. But I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a old post but I have come across the same issue and a solution.

For my SP 2013 farm we use AlwaysOn in SQL 2012 for our databases. For reasons I haven't been able to figure out the primary SQL server fails over to the secondary and this issue pops up with only the Subscription settings service database. I failover again making my 01 database primary as it should be and the normal psconfig command runs without issue.

Now I will try to figure out why this failover is occurring when there are no reboots or issues with the sql box.

Answer (score 0):

For you, is it possible use the following command to update SettingServiceDB?

```
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.type -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Database"}).Provision()
```

Answer (score -2):

if you goto central admin>upgrade and Migration> review database status.

Once you have tyhe databses that need to be upgraded you can either use products config wizard or open a sharepoint powershell up (in admin) run upgrade-spdatabase -identity

If you need the UID run get-spdatabase copy the UID for the database needed if you want to test this do a -whatif at the end of the cmd ie upgrade-spdatabase -identity  whatif

Comment: The right command is **Upgrade-SPContentDatabase** but this command works only on content database.
BdcServiceDatabase and SettingsServiceDB aren't content databases, but thank you anyway

Comment: As @Domenico states, this isn't a valid command for non-Content databases. I have this problem with the StateDatabase, and neither psconfig nor upgrade-spcontentdatabase does any good. I downvoted this answer as it's just a shot in the dark and of no value to the OP.

Comment: -1 as this is not a valid answer for non-content databases.